# Find Majority element in a sorted array in O(lg n) tie complexity

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, binary-search

I am working with this problem and while looking at some of posts I went got a solution with time complexity O(n) using Moore's voting algorithm .
Majority element is that element which occurs more than size of array divided by 2 .
For o(lg n) time following is my code please suggest whether it is in o(lg n).
I welcome suggestions as I am very new to programming .

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std ;

int binarySearch(vector <int> a, int l, int h){

        if(l - h < a.size() / 2)
            return -1;

        int mid = (l+h)/2;
        int temporaryLow = mid;
        int temporaryHigh = mid;

        while(temporaryLow > 0 && a[temporaryLow] == a[mid])
            temporaryLow--;

        while(temporaryHigh < a.size() && a[temporaryHigh] == a[mid])
            temporaryHigh++;

        if((temporaryHigh -1) - (temporaryLow+1) +1 >= a.size()/2){
            return a[mid];
        }else{

            return max(binarySearch(a,0,temporaryLow),binarySearch(a,temporaryHigh,h));

        }
    }

 int findMajority(vector <int> numbers){

        return binarySearch(numbers , 0, numbers.size());
    }


    int main()
    {
        int n ;     
        vector <int> a ;
    while ((cin >> n) && n != 9999)
    a.push_back(n);

        int majority = findMajority(a);
        cout << majority ;
    }
```

Comment: If the array is sorted and has a majority element, the middle element in the array must be the majority element. (In a sorted array equal elements are contiguous. Where could you put more than half of the array's elements avoiding the centre?)

Comment: That is O(1). If you don't know whether or not the array has a majority element, then you have to check that there are a enough instances of the candidate majority element. That verification will take O(log N)

Comment: Hello @rici can you please suggest whether my code is taking O(log N ) , or perhaps suggest some other approach when we don't know that my array has majority element or not .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not O(log n). Idea of binary search is to reduce the search space by half each time, which your code is not doing.

If array is ordered, majority value could be the middle value. To verify this, let ***mid*** be the middle value.

Find the lower_bound and upper_bound of ***mid*** check if difference is greater than half of array size.

***code :***

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int majorityElement(const std::vector<int> &array) {
    auto size = array.size();
    if (!size)
        throw std::runtime_error("no majority element");
    auto mid = array[size/2];
    // These run in O(lg N) because array is sorted
    auto low_index = std::lower_bound(array.cbegin(), array.cend(), mid);
    auto upp_index = std::upper_bound(array.cbegin(), array.cend(), mid);
    if ((upp_index - low_index) > size/2) 
        return mid;
    throw std::runtime_error("no majority element");
}
```

Comment: You might use directly [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range).